# Gradle Dsl method not found: android() android studio 2.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 2.1.3
 guided from [Create Hello-JNI with Android Studio](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2)

Following is output while compile.

> Error:(3, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'FirstDemo' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
>   Fix plugin version and sync project
>
> The project 'FirstDemo' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

build.gradle(module):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sprinkle.firstdemo"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

buil.gradle(top)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

//task clean(type: Delete) {
//    delete rootProject.buildDir
//}
```

Comment: android {} is supposed to be wrapped in model {}. It's in the tutorial.

Comment: Hi I tried with same I was getting Error org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject

Comment: so tried to remove model

Comment: Have you tried without the experimental gradle plugin? I thought the current version of standard plugin supports native code.

Comment: ohh...the reason is android 2.1.3 and tutorial given version. Thanks, I will try with without experimental gradle plugin.

Comment: worked with current version needed to add proguardFiles.add() function in module gradle

Answer (score 0):

Its working

Changed

proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

TO

```
proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
 proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
```

Comment: Proguard-android.txt is in the sdk directory, not in your project directory. Are you sure the rules are actually applied?

Comment: It worked for me , Compiled successfully without any warning/error  in android studio 2.1.3

Comment: Of course it compiled, that's not of question. Did you try to run the release APK?